# Distinguish an etherium transaction to smart contract

Tags: eoa

I'm getting a transaction from Etherium node using RPC. I need to understand if this transaction to Externally Owned Account or to smart contract address. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `to` field of the transaction. It contains the address where the transaction goes.

Ethereum nodes has [`eth_getCode` API to check if this address contains code or not](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getcode). If there is no code, it's EOA.

Answer (score 0):

Dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

So, you can do this using two RPC methods:

- [eth_getCode](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getcode)
- [eth_getTransactionByHash](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-gettransactionbyhash)

> Follow the link to Chainstack docs to learn more about the methods.

Let's explain the logic:

#### eth_getTransactionByHash

- **Purpose:** This method retrieves a transaction by its hash. Every transaction on the Ethereum blockchain has a unique hash, and `eth_getTransactionByHash` uses this hash to find and return the specific transaction's details.
- **Returned Data:** It provides various details about the transaction, including the sender's address (`from`), the recipient's address (`to`), the value transferred, gas details, and more.
- **Usage in Your Context:** after retrieving the transaction using its hash, you are particularly interested in the `to` field. This field contains the address to which the transaction was sent.

#### eth_getCode

- **Purpose:** This method is used to get the bytecode of the account at a specific address. In Ethereum, every smart contract has associated bytecode deployed on the blockchain, whereas EOAs do not.
- **Returned Data:** It returns the contract's bytecode if the specified address is a smart contract. For EOAs, it returns '0x', indicating there is no bytecode (as EOAs don't have associated contract code).
- **Usage in Your Context:** After determining the recipient's address from the `to` field of the transaction, you use `eth_getCode` to check if there is bytecode at that address. If the returned bytecode is anything other than '0x', it indicates that the address is a smart contract. If it is '0x', the address is an EOA.

#### How They Work Together in Your Case:

1. **Retrieve Transaction:** First, you call `eth_getTransactionByHash` (wrapped by `ethers.js` or `web3.js` methods) with the transaction hash to get its details.
2. **Extract Recipient Address:** extract the `to` from the transaction details.
3. **Check for Bytecode:** Then, call `eth_getCode` on the `to` address. If the result is not '0x', it's a smart contract; otherwise, it's an EOA.

This combination of methods provides a reliable way to distinguish between transactions sent to EOAs and those sent to smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain.

### How to code it

Let's now see how to do this using the most common libraries in JavaScript.

#### web3.js

This example uses web3.js v 1.10.0. Install it with `npm i web3@1.10.0`

Then this is the code.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

/**
 * Determines if the given Ethereum address is a smart contract.
 * 
 * @param {string} address - The Ethereum address to check.
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>} - True if the address is a smart contract, false otherwise.
 */
async function isContractAddress(address) {
  try {
    const bytecode = await web3.eth.getCode(address);
    return bytecode !== "0x";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return false;
  }
}

/**
 * Checks the recipient type of a given transaction: EOA or smart contract.
 * 
 * @param {string} transactionHash - The hash of the transaction to check.
 */
async function checkTransactionRecipientType(transactionHash) {
  try {
    const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
    if (!transaction) {
      console.log("Transaction not found");
      return;
    }

    const isContract = await isContractAddress(transaction.to);
    if (isContract) {
      console.log(`Transaction to ${transaction.to} is to a smart contract.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Transaction to ${transaction.to} is to an Externally Owned Account.`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const transactionHash = "0xdf52a6121fa0f0ac010a432501c0416c0daf496ae2fd3346331dd195a0763566";
  await checkTransactionRecipientType(transactionHash);
}

main();
```

#### ethers.js

Install ethers with `npm i ethers`

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

// Connect to the Ethereum network
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "NODE_URL"
);

async function isContractAddress(address) {
  try {
    const code = await provider.getCode(address);
    return code !== "0x";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return false;
  }
}

async function checkTransactionRecipientType(transactionHash) {
  try {
    const transaction = await provider.getTransaction(transactionHash);
    if (!transaction) {
      console.log("Transaction not found");
      return;
    }

    const isContract = await isContractAddress(transaction.to);
    if (isContract) {
      console.log(`Transaction to ${transaction.to} is to a smart contract.`);
    } else {
      console.log(
        `Transaction to ${transaction.to} is to an Externally Owned Account.`
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const transactionHash =
    "0xb69e3b4a654a0f2fa6ec13f5e54befbce38f6e79a16aa32ccb9b13c13cc8b9a2";
  await checkTransactionRecipientType(transactionHash);
}

main();
```

#### Viem

Install Viem with `npm i viem`

```js
import { createPublicClient, http } from "viem";

const transport = http(
  "NODE_URL"
);

const client = createPublicClient({
  transport,
});

async function isContractAddress(address) {
  try {
    const bytecode = await client.getBytecode({
      address: address,
    });

    return bytecode !== undefined;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return false;
  }
}

async function checkTransactionRecipientType(transactionHash) {
  try {
    const transaction = await client.getTransaction({
      hash: transactionHash,
    });
    if (!transaction) {
      console.log("Transaction not found");
      return;
    }

    const isContract = await isContractAddress(transaction.to);
    if (isContract) {
      console.log(`Transaction to ${transaction.to} is to a smart contract.`);
    } else {
      console.log(
        `Transaction to ${transaction.to} is to an Externally Owned Account.`
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const transactionHash =
    "0x4bc0125daa1d64dbc1c9c7912932321466c0f898cb6978e36abef2af6928fb40";
  await checkTransactionRecipientType(transactionHash);
}

main();
```

Just add your RPC URL and edit the transaction hash in the main function. Running it will give you results like this:

```
Transaction to 0x5fdcca53617f4d2b9134b29090c87d01058e27e9 is to a smart contract.

Transaction to 0xea651b91bddbfc6bfdb3e45edebb65ac431d97b1 is to an Externally Owned Account.
```

If you need an RPC feel free to check [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com)! Full disclosure, I work there.

Feel free to reach out if you need more help!